# How do i change metronic ajax table to php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatable

I want the demo ajax table to change in `php mysql` based  but  i'm not able to do that i have tried all but nothing seems to work for me..

[Demo](http://technospike.net/metronic/templates/admin2/table_ajax.html)

```
$iTotalRecords = 178;
  $iDisplayLength = intval($_REQUEST['length']);
  $iDisplayLength = $iDisplayLength < 0 ? $iTotalRecords : $iDisplayLength; 
  $iDisplayStart = intval($_REQUEST['start']);
  $sEcho = intval($_REQUEST['draw']);

  $records = array();
  $records["data"] = array(); 

  $end = $iDisplayStart + $iDisplayLength;
  $end = $end > $iTotalRecords ? $iTotalRecords : $end;

  $status_list = array(
    array("success" => "Pending"),
    array("info" => "Closed"),
    array("danger" => "On Hold"),
    array("warning" => "Fraud")
  );

  for($i = $iDisplayStart; $i < $end; $i++) {
    $status = $status_list[rand(0, 2)];
    $id = ($i + 1);
    $records["data"][] = array(
      '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'">',
      $id,
      '12/09/2013',
      'Jhon Doe',
      'Jhon Doe',
      '450.60$',
      rand(1, 10),
      '<span class="label label-sm label-'.(key($status)).'">'.(current($status)).'</span>',
      '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View</a>',
   );
  }

  if (isset($_REQUEST["customActionType"]) && $_REQUEST["customActionType"] == "group_action") {
    $records["customActionStatus"] = "OK"; // pass custom message(useful for getting status of group actions)
    $records["customActionMessage"] = "Group action successfully has been completed. Well done!"; // pass custom message(useful for getting status of group actions)
  }

  $records["draw"] = $sEcho;
  $records["recordsTotal"] = $iTotalRecords;
  $records["recordsFiltered"] = $iTotalRecords;

  echo json_encode($records);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi i have managed to make it

```
   $counttotrun=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from metronic_table LIMIT $iDisplayStart, $end ");

for($i = $iDisplayStart; $i < $end; $i++)
{
$line_of_text= mysqli_fetch_array($counttotrun);
$records["data"][] = array(
'<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$line_of_text['c1'].'">',
    $line_of_text['c2'],
    $line_of_text['c3'],
    $line_of_text['c4'],
   );

}
```

> hope it helps someone else in future.
>   **Funny** but mostly i figure out my problem myself in stackoverflow :)